# C# Jagged Array int[][][] values not show up properly. In a wrong order

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this jagged array that is not working properly.

```
        private void Sample()
    {
        int[] a0 = { -5, -4, -3, -2, -1 };

        int[][] a1 = { a0, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } };
        int[][] a2 = { new int[] { 4, 5, 6 } };
        int[][] a3 = { new int[] { 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 } };
        int[][] a4 = { new int[] { 12, 13, 14, 15 } };

        int[][][] arr = { a1, a2, a3, a4 };

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].Length; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < arr[j].Length; k++)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(arr[i][j][k].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The result must be -5,-4,-3....13, 14, 15. When i run the method it shows different order, which are -5,-4,1,4,5,7,8,12,13. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Instead of `arr[j].Length` you probably mean to use `arr[i][j].Length`.

Comment: Have you ever met index out of range exception with your code?

Comment: with this sample method i don't encounter it. But the code that i'm working with, there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
for (int k = 0; k < arr[j].Length; k++)
```

to line

```
for (int k = 0; k < arr[i][j].Length; k++)
```